# How can i run two servers in xubuntu 14.04: Mysql server 5.5 & Activemq 5.11

Tags: server, xubuntu, mysql, netbeans

I am developing a web application in netbeans 8.0.2. I have already installed mysql server 5.5 and it was running correctly until i executed the './activemq start' command. The following two error messages were displayed in the screen:

---

**Cannot Connect to Database Server**

Your connection attemp failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306: too many connections

Please:

1 Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1

2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed))

3 Check the root has rights to connect 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql right define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)

4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you are connecting from

---

---

**Error**

Unhandled exception: too many connections (code 1040)

---

Please help me out because my web application in netbeans needs to run both servers at the same time: mysql server and activemq server

Thank you in advance